Checking for form submission failure in Playwright, how to check for error element?
Creating a playwright test for basic form submission works good with the a single expectation on the resulting page after submission:
  test('Create todo', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Next' }).click();
    await expect(page.locator('.todo-summary')).toBeVisible();
  });

but when I start checking for errors, I can't find a good approach for the positive and negative case
  test('Create todo', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Next' }).click();


    // check for errors
    // await page.waitForTimeout(4000);
    await expect(page.locator('.alert-error')).not.toBeVisible();
  });

When the form fails on the server-side and re-renders the form with the, the alert-error div shown, the test is still passing. When I add the waitForTimeout to the page, the test fails as expected.
Shouldn't the expect(locator).not.toBeVisible() be working with or without the waitForTimeout? Or am I missing something key here? What's a good way to check for the error div?

What's the actual page? It's hard to make a recommendation based on what's here, but basically it should likely go like this. Positive case: put some known-good data into the form and click next, assert that the success element is there, and the error isn't. Negative case: put some known bad data into the form that triggers a failure and click next, assert that there's an error on the screen and the success message isn't. Playwright locators always wait, so timing is irrelevant 95% of the time (some specific cases need to dealt with sometimes).

It's hard to make a recommendation without seeing the actual page, but generally it goes like this:

Positive test: put some known-good data into the form and click submit, assert that the success element is there, and the error isn't.
Negative case: put some known bad data into the form that triggers a failure and click submit, assert that there's an error on the screen and the success message isn't.

Playwright locators always wait, so timing is irrelevant 95% of the time (some specific situations require attention to timing, but it's generally ordering of events that matters, not when they happen).
Here's the page we're testing:


const div = document.querySelector("div");
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (document.querySelector("input").value.trim() === "magic word") {
      div.innerHTML = '<div class="todo-summary">Success!</div>';
    }
    else {
      div.innerHTML = '<div class="alert-error">Failure!</div>';
    }
  }, 1000);
});
<form>
  <input placeholder="magic word">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<div></div>



Note that there's some particular user input or state condition that determines whether we expect success or failure. This is important; without it, there's no way to prime the app such that we expect a success state or a failure state and the app is basically untestable. It's not clear what that condition is in your case, but you'll need to identify something (generally, invalid input like a bad password or missing field).
Now we test positive and negative paths:
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<form><input placeholder="magic word"><input type="submit"></form><div></div>
<script>
const div = document.querySelector("div");
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (document.querySelector("input").value.trim() === "magic word") {
      div.innerHTML = '<div class="todo-summary">Success!</div>';
    }
    else {
      div.innerHTML = '<div class="alert-error">Failure!</div>';
    }
  }, 1000);
});
</script></body></html>`;

test("Creates todo on valid input", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.getByPlaceholder("magic word").type("magic word");
  await page.getByRole("button").click();
  await expect(page.getByText("Success")).toBeVisible();
  await expect(page.getByText("Failure")).not.toBeVisible();
});

test("Doesn't create todo on invalid input", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.getByPlaceholder("magic word").type("not magic word");
  await page.getByRole("button").click();
  await expect(page.getByText("Failure")).toBeVisible();
  await expect(page.getByText("Success")).not.toBeVisible();
});

Both tests pass as expected:
Running 2 tests using 1 worker

  ✓  1 todo.test.js:21:1 › Creates todo on valid input (2.0s)
  ✓  2 todo.test.js:29:1 › Doesn't create todo on invalid input (2.0s)

  2 passed (4.5s)

Note that your actual page may involve navigation--this shouldn't change the test, although you can assert await expect(page).toHaveURL("some url") in addition to the page contents.
Technically, this test won't catch a bug where the app shows "Success" on good input, but 4 seconds later switches to "Failure" unexpectedly. That's a pretty unlikely case, so I don't think it's worth explicitly testing unless it's a known issue in your particular app (you have to draw the line somewhere, and you'd have to block for 4 seconds to be certain, which is going to impact test times), but worth keeping in mind.
It's a good idea to make sure your tests fail when they should, by the way. Don't accept a test as working until you do so. Try inverting the assertions or breaking the app. If tests can't identify incorrect behavior, then they're testing the wrong conditions or have some logic error and need to be fixed.

Great explanation, thank you. I created a basic example repo of page and test to try to reproduce what I am attempting to assert and the problem I am seeing - https://github.com/ryanwi/playwright-validation-test .
In this example repo, everything works as expected with both the positive and negative tests.
For my real app, it's still not working as consistently as this, so I'll need to reconcile the differences more.

OK, thanks for that. Can you share the actual app, or reproduce the specific behavior in a simple example? This way, I can see what's going on and solve the problem.
